# Send multidimensional array as out parameter using Oracle stored procedure

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, parameters, out

Please help me under this matter,

1. are we able to create a multidimensional array in an Oracle stored procedure? If so can you explain with an example please?
2. are we able to send the package's as out parameter from an Oracle stored procedure ?

Please help me.

thank you,
shriram

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Package header */
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE exmaple_pkg AS 

    TYPE example_rec IS RECORD(col1 NUMBER, col2 NUMBER );

    TYPE example_ntt IS TABLE OF example_rec;

    PROCEDURE example_proc(parameter_out OUT example_ntt);

END exmaple_pkg;

/* Package body */
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY exmaple_pkg AS 

    PROCEDURE example_proc(parameter_out OUT example_ntt)
    AS
    BEGIN
        parameter_out := example_ntt();
        parameter_out.EXTEND;
        parameter_out(1).col1 := 11;
        parameter_out(1).col2 := 22;
    END example_proc;

END exmaple_pkg;

/* Call the procedure */
DECLARE
    l_variable exmaple_pkg.example_ntt;
BEGIN
    exmaple_pkg.example_proc(l_variable);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col1:' || l_variable(1).col1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col2:' || l_variable(1).col2);
END;

/* The result */
col1:11
col2:22
```